# which member of a least residue system will regenerate the system under addition?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

In general, the set of integers {0, 1, 2, …, n − 1} is called the least residue system modulo n.

For example, the least residue system of $12$ is

$${0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}$$

If we repeatedly add 5 within this system then we will have

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
5n & 5 & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40 & 45 & 50 & 55 & 60 \\ 
\mod 12 & 5 & 10 & 3 & 8 & 1 & 6 & 11 & 4 & 9 & 2 & 7 & 0
\end{array}$$

and 5 ends up "generating" the least residue system again. Also adding 6 generates the system under addition as well. But 2, 3, 4, 7,8,9, and 10 do not. Though it is clear that adding $1$ or $(n-1)$ generates the system under addition.

First question: I am curious about when to be able to identify non-trivial examples (like 5mod12 or 6mod12) for a given least residue system. Is there a well known result concerning this?

(My guess is it has something to do with GCDs, but I don't know too much number theory. Literally had to comb through wikipedia to find out that the set I was thinking about was called "a least residue system")

Second: it seems the case that if $n$ is prime then each number within the least residue system generates the system under addition as well. What is this result called?

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say that $6$ generates the same group? You only get $0$ and $6$. In fact, the numbers $1,5,7,9$ and $11$ generate the group.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. In my mind it was "skipping" 6 (adding 7) that reproduced the system. You are correct adding 6 definitely does not generate the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim that $7$ does not generate the system is not correct. It should be $6$ that does not.  Any number coprime to the system will do so, which is the result you are looking for.  To show that 
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
7n & 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 & 56 & 63 & 70 & 77 & 84 \\ 
\mod 12 & 7 & 2 & 9 & 4 & 11 & 6 & 1 & 8 & 3 & 10 & 5 & 0
\end{array}$$

Comment: Good catch! I got mixed up. And the fact that they need to be coprimes makes sense. Thanks!